# Find an upper bound of $\frac{d^{n+1}}{d^{n+1} x} \exp(-x) \cos(4\pi x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How can I find an upper bound of $\frac{d^{n+1}}{d^{n+1} x} \exp(-x) \cos(4\pi x)$? That is, for $f^{(n+1)}$? Note that x is in the interval $(0,3)$. I have been told the following hint: How many terms are in $f^{(n+1)}$ and what is an upper bound for each of them? I then spent 2 hours and finally gave up and now I'd try to reach out to some true math wizards :)

The cos and sin terms are upper bounded by 1. Also I believe that $exp(-x) \leq exp(0) = 1$

Comment: Are you allowed to use complex numbers?

Comment: Here's a hint: take the first 5 or 6 derivatives, and see if you can find a pattern.  Use the triangle inequality $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$, and the fact that $e^{-x}\leq 1$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @Andrei It shouldn't be necessary I think. We are only considering the real case in my class.

Comment: @ThatGuy I think you can get a more elegant solution using complex numbers. See the answer from J.G. below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andrei's hint is useful. You can improve on this, but:$$\begin{align}D^{n+1}\exp(-x)\cos(4\pi x)&\stackrel{1}{=}\Re D^{n+1}\exp((-1+4\pi i)x)\\&\stackrel{2}{=}\Re((-1+4\pi i)^{n+1}\exp((-1+4\pi i)x))\\&\stackrel{3}{\le}|((-1+4\pi i)^{n+1}\exp((-1+4\pi i)x))|\\&\stackrel{4}{=}(1+16\pi^2)^{(n+1)/2}\exp(-x)\\&\stackrel{5}{<}(1+16\pi^2)^{(n+1)/2}.\end{align}$$Here 1 uses $\cos y=\exp iy$ for $y\in\Bbb R$, 2 uses $De^{zx}=ze^{zx}$ for $z\in\Bbb C$, 3 uses $\Re z\le|z|$ for $z\in\Bbb C$, 4 uses $|\exp iy|=1$ for $y\in\Bbb R$, and 5 uses $e^{-x}<1$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Can you please associate some explanatory words with the steps?

Comment: @ThatGuy See edit.

Comment: Ah okay, that helped! But what is the R? And is the D representing the differential part?

Comment: @ThatGuy $D$ means $d/dx$; $\Re z$ is the real part of $z$.